# Facebook PHP form returns empty $_POST

Tags: php, facebook, forms, post, facebook-graph-api

I've been developing some Facebook apps lately and I always had the same problem: I can't find a way to send a form with a POST method on iFrame Facebook apps. The returned `$_POST` is always empty.

One patch I found is to send my data using a form using a GET method and to send it to the canvas page script URL, just like this: `<form action="<?php echo CANVAS_PAGE; ?>script.php" method="GET" >`
and then to get my data through `$_REQUEST`.
I tried any combination of POST /GET method with `CANVAS_PAGE/script.php` / `CANVAS_URL/script.php` / `script.php` action and this is only thing that actually works. AT least for me.

Now, the problem I have is that I need to upload a file and then I must use the POST method and then back to the initial problem -> I can't find a way to send a form with a POST method. The returned `$_POST` is always empty!!

Anybody has an answer to that?

Comment: you may want to select some answers to your previous questions or people won't want to help you

Comment: Have a read through the Stack Overflow FAQ. You've had five months to get around to it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer found.

The post method in Facebook works fine as long as you pass the $_REQUEST["signed_request"] as a hidden field called "signed_request" in your form.

Comment: I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK 3.0 and building a canvas (iframe) app and was able to pass and retrieve POST data using your answer. Thanks for following up.

Comment: Here's where I'm getting stuck. How do I combine a friend-selector with an html form so I can input information for my database and select a friend those choices should be sent to?

Comment: I have a hidden field in my form called signed_request, but i keep geting empty post... maybe is it due oct. 1 new changes, ssl, etc.? I do have ssl cert

Comment: Set this enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and now working